# XORing two fractions of integers

Tags: boolean-algebra, fractions, integers, binary-operations

I was wondering if it is possible to apply the XOR operator between two fractions of integers. `2 ⨁ 13 = 0010 ⨁ 1101 = 1111 = 15`.

`2 = 6/3` and `13 = 26/2`. So how does one compute `6/3 ⨁ 26/2`?
Does the rules for summing two fractions apply for XORing two fractions? Because `6/3 ⨁ 26/2 != (12^78)/6`.

Comment: That's not how it works. You ask whether it is possible to define such-and-such rules, then you ask what are the rules. There are no rules. There is no asking "what". The rules are simply not there yet. One has to **define** them beforehand. Actually, _you_ have to do that.

Comment: What do you mean? How should I proceed?

Comment: I wish I could have said the same more plainly and/or more assertively, but my command of English is only as good as it is, so bear with me. Imagine a brick. I mean, a literal brick from fire-dried clay, taken out of a century-old building. Now try to find a memory card slot on it, like they make on modern smartphones. Guess what? You won't be able to find it, because it is **not there**. That's how much "not there" are the rules that you want.